# get sub object data to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

[image: object data]

I have the object from the console  like the following

```
object { 0: div#ch2.group-item, 1: div#ch4.group-item, length: 2 }
```

I want to convert it to array  ids [ch2,ch4]

```
var ids=$.each(children, function() { return $(this).attr('id'); });
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: Can you add your original data,please?

Comment: how do you get the `children` array, do you select the element by vanilla javascript or jquery?

Comment: Ideally you also tell whether you are using a JQuery package, and which version, and spending few words to give some context helps future user to find things better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to use jquery [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) instead of [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

For example.

```js
const children = $('li');

const result = $.map(children, (item) => item.id)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="one">
    first
  </li>
    <li id="two">
    second
  </li>
    <li id="three">
    third
  </li>
    <li id="four">
    fourth
  </li>
    <li id="five">
    fivth
  </li>
</ul>
```